# Vitamin and mineral contents of common fruits

Tags: nutrition

I'm looking for nutritional data, mostly vitamin and mineral contents of common fruits, such as apples, bananas, oranges, kiwis etc.

Are there scientific (published and peer-reviewed) sources that list or compare those? I spent an hour on Google Scholar but most of the sources there discuss only a small aspect (e.g. vitamin C content) or compare different states of fruits (frozen, fresh, canned). I'm not well educated in human nutritional aspects so I may overlook this one keyword to search for.

I'm aware of tables on the Internet discussing these aspects but I need a solid scientific basis.

Comment: Found a source that seems somewhat reliable: http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/

Comment: Do you want to answer the question yourself (which is perfectly ok), or shall I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I know two databases for such information: The "National Nutrient Database for Standard Reference" (reference 1) from the United States Department of Agriculture (which you list yourself) and the "Nutrition Data" (reference 2) Database. Both allow searching for specific foods and give the values back. I like the second more, since it gives you the complete output it has and you don't have to choose three single nutrients like for the USDA database.

References:

1. [USDA National Nutrient Database for Standard Reference](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/)
2. [Nutrition Data](http://nutritiondata.self.com/)